# How to create an additional input method service without changing default selected one?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I want to make a new input method with no actual keyboard.
It should stay active (after being enabled by user) always but not be the default keyboard. Because it will not have any visual keyboard and user will still be able to use the default keyboard as he/she selects.

I will trigger it on demand from a network command. Is this possible ?
It should be possible, because for example Android TV remote or Shield TV remote can do this.

But I couldn't find how to do it. When I create a normal input method, it only works if I select it as the default input method.

```
    <service android:name="SoftKeyboard"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>
```

This is the part from manifest file. Is it possible to make it work without selecting it as the default input method ?
As a second, additional input method …

Comment: "Is this possible ?" -- I don't think so. Having input methods that the user did not select be able to run would be a major security problem. "It should be possible, because for example Android TV remote or Shield TV remote can do this." -- they are not input methods from Android's standpoint, any more than a Bluetooth mouse is.

Comment: I am saying that the user will not select it. User will enable it by his will. But it will not be default for input. I just want it to be a side input method. Otherwise, user will have to change input method everytime he wants to use my service. Actually, you are correct, I want to make something similar to a Bluetooth mouse. User will send commands to it from a different platform (Smartthings Hub) . So how can I do that ?

Comment: "I just want it to be a side input method" -- then it will never do anything. Only the user's chosen active input method can provide input. Anything else would be a security problem. "So how can I do that ?" -- you are welcome to look into the accessibility APIs. However, check with your preferred app distribution channel to see if you will be able to distribute the app. Google, for example, has been threatening to block apps that use the accessibility for things other than accessibility (e.g., helping visually-impaired or motor-impaired users).

Comment: thanks. actually distribution is not my problem , because I am doing this for myself. I can of course distribute the APK to the users of Smartthings Hub, but that's not my focus  at the moment.  Btw, I am not sure if Input method service is not suitable for this, because my Shield TV has a keyboard named "virtual remote keyboard" which enables me to use my Android phone as a remote controller. How does it work ?

Comment: The device manufacturer can do things that an ordinary app developer cannot.

Comment: ok. thanks. in this case I should look for other methods to input DPAD_LEFT, DPAD_RIGHT etc. I can call "input keyevent"  from ADB shell. But when I do this through my app it is not allowed. How can I do it with accessibility or other methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a solution which could live together with the original leanback keyboard.
So, I found an example Leanback keyboard code , injected my rest API in it.
Now I have the leanback keyboard modified to make what I want.